# Second Order Time Integration for Stiff Linear System Avoiding any Explicit Step

Tags: time-integration, stiffness

I have a linear system

$$
\dot x(t) = Ax(t), \quad x(0)=x_0 \tag{*}
$$

with $A$ being *Hurwitz* (i.e. the solutions may oscillate but will eventually tend to zero) but really *stiff*. $A$ might be large, but I can do explicit solves.

I want to integrate it in time. Since it is coupled with a flow solver, stability is my primary concern. However, since my flow is integrated with order 2, I would fancy a 2nd order scheme for $(*)$ too.

I found that the **implicit trapezoidal rule** gives accurate and stable solutions. But the oscillations in the initial phase will likely destroy my simulation.

That's why I went for **BDF2**. Here, however, I face the problem of the initialization (I need a second order approximation of the value at the first time step computed with a different scheme). The canonical choice of **Heun's method** led to extreme overshoots in the approximation. Things slightly improve when I use an *Implicit Euler* step for the prediction. But the correction step is still explicit and produces the overshoot.

In both cases, a smaller time step improves things -- but I don't want to go to small.

---

**So my question is:**
Is there a method that gives my a second order increment of

$$x(0)=x_0\to x_1\approx x(0+h)$$

that completely avoids the explicit application of $A$?

---

Below are plots of my numerical tests. I have cropped the y-axis to better see what is happening.

*Trapezoidal rule*:
[image: trapezoidal rule]

*BDF2* with one step *Heun* for initialization:
[image]

For comparison: *Implicit Euler*:
[image]

---

EDIT-2: some more plots

Actually, in the above plots, only the output of the system was shown, namely $y=Cx$, where $x$ is the state and $C$ is a constant matrix.

Plot of $x$ computed with the *Implicit Euler* scheme:
[image]

Plot of $y=Cx$ computed with the trapezoidal rule
[image]

Close up for the trapezoidal rule on the initial phase -- large time step:
[image]

Close up for the trapezoidal rule on the initial phase -- small time step:
[image]

EDIT: some words on the system (matrices)...

The system derives from a semi-discrete approximation of the incompressible Navier-Stokes equations that is coupled to a controller. In theory, it reads

\begin{align}
\dot v &= \Pi \tilde A(v) + \Pi f (v) + B\hat C \hat v \\
\dot{\hat v} &= \hat A \hat v + \hat B C v
\end{align}

with a nonlinearity $f$ and a projector $\Pi=I-J^T(JJ^T)J$ for some matrix $J$.

In the practical realization, I cannot use the projector $\Pi$ but it's realization through solving saddle point systems. E.g., one step of the implicit trapezoidal rule will read like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{k+1} \\ \hat v_{k+1} \\ \sim 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
I - \frac{h}{2} \tilde A & - \frac{h}{2}B\hat C & -J^T \\
 - \frac{h}{2}\hat BC & I - \frac{h}{2}\hat A & 0 \\
-J & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
I + \frac{h}{2} \tilde A & \frac{h}{2}B\hat C &  0 \\
  \frac{h}{2}\hat BC & I + \frac{h}{2}\hat A & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{k} \\ \hat v_{k} \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here, $\tilde A$, $J$ are large but sparse matrix of size, say, $10^5$. The matrix $\hat A$ is small (of size ~100).

Comment: Your stiff system admits the exact solution $e^A x_0$, being $e^A$ the matrix exponential. You might use the analytical solution in place of $x_1$, i.e. $x_1 = e^A x_0$, but this of course depends on the matrix $A$ as the matrix exponential is not a trivial task, and its accuracy strongly depends on the matrix. Could you provide us your $A$? I think that some *ad-hoc* technique like exponential integrators could solve the problem

Comment: An exponential integrator might be a remedy. However, there are two more caveats to my problem. (1) the linear system is but a part of an implicit-explicit integration. (2) in my application, I don't have the $A$ explicitly available but only applications of $A$ or $(I-sA)^{-1}$. I will add some explanation of the system to the body. If you still think that it might be worth a try, I can provide the matrices at least of the linear part.

Comment: Indeed, an exponential integrator does not require the whole $A$ explicitely, but only its action on a vector $v$.

Comment: Or you may just compute $e^A x_0$ and then use BFD-2. The point is that to compute $e^A x_0$ you can use a tailored highly accurate routine for the matrix exponential, so that the first step is exact up to machine precision @Jan

Comment: OK. You mean $e^{hA}x_0$. That is just the first step -- cool idea, actually.

Comment: Yes, of course $h$ was missing :-) Now you only have to choose a suitable method to compute the action, which strongly depends on $A$ of course. You have complex eigenvalues with large negative real part, right?

Comment: Yes, complex eigenvalues with negative real parts. But with magnitudes between `1e-1` and `1e8`

Comment: I see. Just out of curiosity, what is the matrix that you actually have to exponentiate? $\tilde{A}$ or $\hat{A}$? @Jan

Comment: It's not clear to me -- do you believe the early oscillations are part of the true solution, or that they are numerical artifacts?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Hi David, thanks for showing your interest. I believe the early oscillations are a numerical artifact -- since they are to be expected with the trapezoidal rule and since the get less with smaller time steps. I have added a few more plots to the question.

Comment: @VoB the matrix that I have to exponentiate would be $[\Pi \tilde A \; B\hat C ; \hat BC \; \hat A]$ -- where the $\Pi$ is only available as a linear operator $v\to \Pi v$ (where $v$ is a vector)

Comment: Btw I think that CN, which is essentially the trapezoidal rule, is not the right choice: it's not L-stable (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466978/advantage-of-l-stability-compared-to-a-stability/1467287) so I would avoid it actually. Indeed, BackwardEuler correctly reproduce the boundary layer, as it is L-stable @Jan

Comment: This may be relevant to your problem https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2019.04.070

Comment: As expected, L-stability here is the key problem "BDF2 should be started with a second-order L-stable scheme such as SDIRK" . Thanks @cfdlab for the reference :)

Comment: @cfdlad yes -- good to see this referenced. Anyone in the mood to make this a short answer so I can accept it...?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to be completely certain, but I suspect that what you need is just an L-stable method (note that BDF2 and backward Euler are L-stable, while the implicit trapezoidal method is not).  There are plenty of high-order (2+) L-stable one-step methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments for the original discussion.

The lack of L-stability of the trapezoidal rule in the first step is the source of your problem. A simpler and famous toy problem that shows the point is the *Curtiss-Hirschfelder* equation $$y'=-2000(y-\cos(t)) \\y(0)=0$$

Integrating this with Backward Euler and the Trapezoidal rule gives the following result (I wrote the easy routine myself for illustration purposes, without using `odeint` or other libraries)

[[image: Integration up to <span class=]$T=0.5$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz8gy.png)

[[image: Integration up to <span class=]$T=10.0$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrDPv.png)

obtained with the following Python snippet

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
# Trapz rule is NOT L-stable! (While Backward Euler is)
# Test equation: y'(t)=-2000*(y-cos(t)), y(0)=0
C = -2000

def Fun(t,x):
    return C*(x-np.cos(t))
    
tf=10.0
t0=0
ts=100
k=(tf-t0)/ts
t=np.linspace(t0,tf,ts+1)
y=np.zeros((ts+1)) #trapz
yE=np.zeros((ts+1)) #Backward Euler
y0=0
y[0]=y0
yE[0]=y0

for i in range (0,ts):
    y[i+1] = (y[i]+0.5*k*(Fun(t[i],y[i]) -C*np.cos(t[i+1]) ) ) /(1.0-0.5*k*C)
    yE[i+1] = (yE[i] + k*C*(-np.cos(t[i+1])) )/(1-k*C)

plt.plot(t,y,marker='o',label='Trapezoidal')
plt.plot(t,yE,marker='d',label='Backward Euler')
plt.title("Integration up to T="+str(tf))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

As pointed out in the reference from @cfdlab: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2019.04.070 Indeed we can read:

> BDF2 should be started with a second-order L-stable scheme such as SDIRK.

which is exactly your problem. The good point is that BDF2 is L-stable, so as long as you take an L-stable method with order 2 as first step, you'll have a second order scheme which won't have those wild oscillations at the beginning

Another way could be to choose as first step the exact solution which would require to compute $e^{h A}x_0$ with some suitable routine for the action of the matrix exponential.

Comment: Would you mind, providing a 2nd plot with a finer time step. I'm curious about the initial oscillations that are also seen in the *backward Euler* scheme.

Comment: There was an error in my BE :-) Now it's fine, thanks for pointing this out. I've added also the Python snippet with whom I got the plots @Jan